# Scale textures well in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I'm using a 3rd party class called TextureScale (http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=TextureScale) which scales Texture2Ds in Unity. I have been able to use TextureScale.Point() to scale my textures, but it gives me low quality results. I wanted to try TextureScale.Bilinear() instead, but it gives me an empty texture when I do. There is no error. What am I doing wrong? But I am not sure that this would give me better results because I found this (http://jon-martin.com/?p=114) which seems to scale using Bilinear and the result is still low quality.

Is there a better way to scale textures in Unity and get ok results? Note that the source textures are significantly bigger (at least 4x) than the size I am scaling them to. Also, there is text in the images.

Thank you

Comment: It probably has something to do with your import options on your texture. Point, Bilinear, or Trilinear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I saw that there were many optimizations that Unity does on imported textures. The offending one in this case was 'Create Mip Maps'. With this unchecked the textures looked much better.

Answer (score 1):

[Textures Adjustments](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/37732) asset offers about x100 faster GPU accelerated texture scale/resizing solutions then [TextureScale](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=TextureScale) from wiki.unity3d.com